# Jquery load() live results?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple page that when the submit button is clicked I load a page using `load()`

eg:

```
$("#res").load("do.php");
```

**do.php** contains a few simple command that are run and return the results to screen.

If I run **do.php** directly in my browser I get the results displayed on screen in real time as they script runs then and gets the results back.

However when called from another page using `load()` I only get the results page once **do.php** has completely finished.

Is there any way to call **do.php** from another page and have its results returned live ?

do.php contains simple commands similar to:

```
<?php
$cmd = 'ping 127.0.0.1';

while (@ ob_end_flush());

$proc = popen($cmd, 'r');
echo '<pre>';
while (!feof($proc))
{
    echo fread($proc, 4096);
    @ flush();
}
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Can we have the code for `do.php`?

Comment: @D4V1D - Original post updated

Comment: Is this possible ? I've tried all the ways I can think of, but I have to wait for the values to load before they are displayed.

Comment: That seems logicial. As the PHP script is not yet finished, the request is still pending, therefore the `success` callback (or `.done()`) is not fired until the PHP script is complete.